# Genre/Sex to numeric in R

Tags: r, transformation, numeric

Is there a more efficient way to create a numeric column with gender? The `Sex` column has values `"male"` and `"female"` with no `null` values, and `factor` dtype.

```
train$Sex_num <- as.character(train$Sex)
train$Sex_num[train$Sex=="male"]<-1
train$Sex_num[train$Sex=="female"]<-0
train$Sex_num <- as.numeric(train$Sex_num)
table(train$Sex_num)
```

**EDIT**

Efficient: Less lines of code.

Comment: What does efficient mean? This is probably already pretty fast. Do you want "neater" code?

Comment: @CalumYou yes, less lines of code!

Comment: @pnuts you are right, gender is the word. Thanks !

Comment: train <- within(train, sexnum <- sex == "male") and then use as.numeric although it shouldn't be necessary since logical is the appropriate data type.

Comment: You say it's a factor already, so `train$Sex_num = as.integer(train$Sex) - 1`. Short and efficient, though I like Roland's better for clarity.

Comment: I'd encourage you to rename it to something where the meaning of the value is obvious. "male" and "female" have obvious meanings, but sex = 1 or sex = 0, who can say? If you want males to be 1, then name the column `is_male`, `is_male = 1` means male quite clearly.

Comment: If the data type is of type "factor" then column is all ready a number, as.integer(train$Sex)  will convert the column into 1s and 2s.  Which is which will depend on how the data was entered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ifelse` is pretty efficient. Try

```
train$Sex_num <- ifelse(train$Sex=="male", 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

just remove the Sex column and create an is_male column. You can directly coerce a logical vector to numeric without needing to specify `female` separately.

```
train$is_male <- as.integer(train$Sex == "male")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many good & efficient answers already provided for the question. But sometimes I feel `named-vector` (vector with attributes) should be considered good alternatives in cases like this.

```
sexType <- c(female = 0, male = 1, other = 2)
train$Sex_num <- sexType[train$Sex]
```

I have added another option as `other` to demonstrate flexibility but that is not needed scenario mentioned by OP.